# Covering unreachable default clause in switch case in java

Tags: java, junit, enums, mockito, switch-statement

I have below code snippet, and I'm not sure how to cover the default clause with a unit test.

```java
public Block solve(String str) {

    try {
            
        final BlockType blockType = BlockType.valueOf(str);

        switch (blockType) {
            case TEXTBLOCK:
                return ...
            case IMAGEBLOCK:
                return ...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum BlockType {
    IMAGEBLOCK("imageBlock"),
    TEXTBLOCK("textBlock");

    private String value;
}
```

NOTE: I have the constraint that the argument in `solve` method has to be of `String` type only. Also, I don't want to add any dummy value in my enum just for testing purpose.

Comment: You do not need to cover everything with a unit test. But generally returning `null` is a very idea.

Comment: @luk2302 I assume: very bad idea :)

Comment: You cannot add a test that covers the default clause here. Also, you may want to consider moving logic to the individual enum instances, instead of using a switch, then your code can be `return blockType.someMethod()`, removing the need for the switch (and its default) entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If the default case is really unreachable (as in your case), you have two options:

1. You just drop it.
2. You throw an error instead of returning `null`:

   ```
   switch( blockType ) 
   {
       case TEXTBLOCK:
           return ...
       case IMAGEBLOCK:
           return ...
       default: throw new AssertionError( "Invalid blockType: " + blockType.name() );
   }
   ```

   In this case, you learn *really* fast that something does not work in case you add an additional `BlockType` enum value, instead of some spurious `NullPointerExceptions` occurring far away from the `switch`.

But in regard of your original question: you cannot test it without massively modifying your code. But this is not uncommon for "safety nets" like this default label.

Comment: I guess the real answer would be to eliminate the switch/case entirely and instead define and override a method inside the enum constants.

Comment: I'd suggest using `AssertionError` instead of just `Error`.

Comment: @f1sh , can you please add more details like how to do that or a code snippet if possible ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel – In my code, I defined an `UnexpectedEnumError`, derived from `AssertionError` for this purpose. So yes, it should not be just `Error`.

Comment: @f1sh – If you have just two enum values as in the sample, replacing the `switch` by an `if` could be an option. But if there are more, the `switch` is the better approach, also if it would be possible to have more enum values in the future. So in general, the real answer is ***not*** to eliminate the `switch`.

Comment: @tquadrat why? You can attach the relevant code directly to the enum constant. There is no need for a switch, not even when thinking about extending the enum in the future.

Comment: @f1sh – In case the ellipse after `return` stands for `blockType.getValue()` you might be correct. But as this is unclear, the missing code could be anything, including stuff that does not work as a method for an enum because it is not generic enough …

Comment: @tquadrat what does "not generic enough" mean? Just define+override a method for each constant and pass everything you need as a parameter. That covers everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do get coverage of the `default` case in your example.  But it is nasty.

First, we need to understand why the `default` case in your example is not marked as unreachable code.  This is a logical consequence of the rules for evolution of `enum` classes as set out in [JLS 13.4.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.26).  These say that adding extra constants to an existing `enum` does not break binary compatibility.

Thus, while the `default` branch in your example is not effectively reachable *at the time that the code was compiled*, it *could* become reachable if another constant is added to the `enum` later on.  And the Java compiler *doesn't* flag the `default` branch as unreachable code ... as you can see!

So ... the *nasty* way to get 100% unit test coverage for the `default` branch in your example is to simulate the code evolution.  Write an alternate version of the `enum` class with an extra constant, and then write a unit test that feeds that constant to the code with that `switch` statement.

> Also, I don't want to add any dummy value in my enum just for testing purpose.

That's not what is going on.  What we are doing is simulating a (hypothetical) *future* version of the `enum`.  The *current* version doesn't have the extra constant.

<sup>Making it work in the context of a typical unit test framework and a typical Java build tool is left as an exercise to the reader.</sup>

Is it a good idea to do this?  IMO no!  It is better to acknowledge that it is (typically) not worthwhile going to extremes to "achieve" 100% coverage.  Indeed, if you have a "this should never happen" case in your code, there is no value in trying to make that condition actually happen during testing.

<sup>But ... if it is a design goal for your application to *deal* with evolution of the `enum`, then achieving coverage of the unreachable `default` case is maybe justifiable.</sup>

---

However ... returning `null` in this case is really bad idea; see the comments and the above answer for reasons why, and what you can do instead.